# Dependency Injection on external classes c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, oop, dependency-injection, refactoring

I am trying to refactor my code by introducing Dependency Injection for my class dependencies.

I have two classes that third-party sources have provided.
One is an abstract class that contains virtual methods, and I have created my class MyOverridenClass, to implement actual code. This class depends on ACustomClass, which I am instantiating in the constructor. But I want to inject this dependency into the MyOverridenClass rather than creating the instance there only.

```
public class MyOverridenClass : ThirdPartyAbstractClass
{

   public MyOverridenClass()
   {
      ACustomClass cc = new ACustomClass();
   }
   public override void SomeOverridenMethod()
   {
   }
}
```

The same third-party source has also provided another class called the MyOverridenClass class. But the actual execution is hidden(not known to us).

```
public class CallingClass
{
}

CallingClass c = new CallingClass();
c.CallingClassMethod(); // TO call the above implemented MyOverridenClass class
```

So now, the problem is that we can create only one default constructor (provided) in MyOwnClass. Therefore I can't find a way to handle dependency injection.

I have only thought of using the ServiceLocator pattern.

But any other ideas?

Comment: If classes are constructing their dependencies in their own constructors, then there's not really anything you can do. Your own constructor would still implicitly call he parameterless base constructor.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama: sorry which class u r talking about. So one is MyOverridenClass which is called by CallingClass. For this I cant do anything. Then another is ACustomClass which is getting instantiating in the ctor of MyOverridenClass. Dependency ACustomClass  I wanted to inject in MyOverridenClass

Comment: I didn't really follow your example, to be honest. I was just trying to give general information.